# Heroku getting started PHP doesnt run locally

Tags: php, heroku

I have cloned the heroku php getting started app and ran 'composer update' to install all dependencies, including the heroku build pack as a dev dependency.

Now when I run 'heroku local' I get the following error, and I'm not quite sure what they mean, finding little info online. Pushing the app to Heroku and it runs fine there.

```
web.1  | AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Warrens-iMac.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
web.1  | DOCUMENT_ROOT changed to 'web/'
web.1  | 4 processes at 128MB memory limit.
web.1  | Starting php-fpm...
web.1  | Starting httpd...
web.1  | Application ready for connections on port 5000.
web.1  | httpd: Syntax error in -C/-c directive: Include takes one argument, Name(s) of the config file(s) to be included; fails if the wildcard does not match at least one file
web.1  | Process exited unexpectedly: httpd
web.1  | Going down, terminating child processes...
web.1  | [Wed Dec  2 10:55:49 2015]  Script:  '-'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this? I think most people typically just run their own PHP server locally which is probably why this hasn't gotten an answer yet. I just checked the Heroku PHP docs and a month later they still haven't address this too.